# How to change IP to connect to ROS from a browser using ROSBRIDGE without changing the code [closed]

Tags: ros, rosbridge, robotwebtools, roslibjs, websocket

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear community,

I have tried to design a web page that allows me to connect to ROS via ROSBRIDGE. If I want to connect to master I have to change the IP in the code using roslibjs like:

var ros = new ROSLIB.Ros({
url : 'ws://192.168.1....:9090'
});

But I want to allow the person that is using the browser to change the IP and connect to any computer using ROS without having to change the code. For example, having a text input to write the IP direction and after it just clicking a button connect to ROS. I have tried to use a function that changes the URL data (IP) and the problem is that the Java containing the functions to connect to ROS are executed at the beginning when I open the web and not when I want to execute it, after typing the IP address.

I have seen that in Robot Web Tools they have an web page named ROSWEB that allows you to make it but I don't understand how they can do it.

Is there any way to get this?

Thanks you for reading my question

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271092/how-to-change-ip-to-connect-to-ros-from-a-browser-using-rosbridge-without-changing-the-code-%5Bclosed%5D/) by [alberhhh](https://answers.ros.org/users/30925/alberhhh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-09-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-20**:
This is not an answer, but: what you describe is more a javascript / html(5) development issue than a ROS issue. Yes, Robot Web Tools interacts with ROS, but it's really just a javascript library, and should be treated that way.
You might want to look at more javascript/webdev focused fora.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The best way is to instantiate the `var ros = new ROSLIB.Ros({ url : 'ws://192.168.1....:9090' });` only when the user informs the `IP` and click `Submit`.

Not automatically instantiate when the page is loaded.

---

Originally posted by [Ruben Alves](https://answers.ros.org/users/25452/ruben-alves/) with karma: 1038 on 2017-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1